# How to remove the specific class

Tags: css, html

[image]I have removed schema through plugin but few lines of class still appearing on my website header.

Comment: That's not schema. That's HTML. Your header template is broken because you've got an image in the middle of the body tag. Have you tried to add a background image to `<body>` or something?

Comment: Yes, I used the plugin so that I can see the header image across all pages of my website.

Comment: What plugin? It's broken your site.

Comment: Yes, It is broking my site Plugin name  "WP Header Images". when I deactivate the error went away, but when I activate it, it casing the same error mentioned above on the top of my website.

Comment: Then you will need to take it up with the plugin author. They seem very responsive: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-header-images/

Comment: Thanks @Jacob Peattie.

Comment: Anyone can help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the below code from the header.php inside the activated theme.

```
<?php body_class(); ?>
```